# Libvirt & USB Hub Passthrough

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I have a virtual machine which I wish to have a USB Hub and all of its devices allocated to a virtual machine.

The Hub in question is a USB hub which itself is plugged into one of the ports on the motherboard / main linux hub.

I've tried a few different methods and haven't found a solution.

I'm using Libvirt on a Ubuntu 15.10 Host. I've tried using the hostdev method and tried the line of code at [Pass an USB hub from a KVM host to a guest with libvirt](https://serverfault.com/questions/667426/pass-an-usb-hub-from-a-kvm-host-to-a-guest-with-libvirt) with no success.

Thanks -
Ryan Walmsley